# how to hide and show in html element dynamically

Tags: html

html input element hide and show using link tag.
example:yahoo mail Bcc hide and show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is done in Javascript.

For simple Javascript, i.e. without using `jQuery` you can do that:

```
document.getElementById("idOfElement").style.display = "none"; // to hide    
document.getElementById("idOfElement").style.display = "block"; // to show
```

[Here is a link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp) with the possible values for this `display` CSS element.

Comment: The link appears to be dead (2018) but I found a similar answer: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

yahoo does this with javascript.

using plaing JS on the `onlick` of a link:

```
document.getElementById('someDiv').style.display = 'block'; //or 'none' to hide
```

using a JS library like jQuery:

```
$('#someDiv').show(); //or .hide();
```

Comment: `display = "show"` ? Is it a valid value for this CSS property?